# ELB(Classic Load Balancer) Proxy Protocol Not working on Kubernetes Cluster

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-elb, amazon-eks, aws-elb

- Created K8s Cluster on AWS (EKS).
- Created Deployment workload.
- Created Service Type Loadbalancer with annotation service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-proxy-protocol: "*"
  (Which should enable proxy protocol on ELB) for TCP Port 4334.

So in my pod I am not able to see the Proxy protocol preserving the client IP.
Tried packet sniffers and tcpdump but no where I can see that client IP is preserved by protocol.

Can anybody tell me how to verify proxy protocol is preserving the client IP ?

Refer the Load balancer mentioned below. It has a policy named "k8s-proxyprotocol-enabled" which is applied on 'BackendServerDescriptions' on Instance port 31431.

One thing I observed is that in 'ListenerDescriptions'  for instance port 31431 policy name is empty. For proxy protocol to work as expected is it required to have 'k8s-proxyprotocol-enabled' should be applied on listener policy in listener description?

Can anyone confirm below config is sufficient for Proxy protocol to preserve source IP or extra config has to be done?

```
"LoadBalancerDescriptions": [
    {
        "Subnets": [
            "subnet-1",
            "subnet-2",
            "subnet-2"
        ],
        "CanonicalHostedZoneNameID": "******",
        "CanonicalHostedZoneName": "*************",
        "ListenerDescriptions": [
            {
                "Listener": {
                    "InstancePort": 31431,
                    "LoadBalancerPort": 4334,
                    "Protocol": "TCP",
                    "InstanceProtocol": "TCP"
                },
                "PolicyNames": []
            }
        ],
        "HealthCheck": {
            "HealthyThreshold": 2,
            "Interval": 10,
            "Target": "TCP:31499",
            "Timeout": 5,
            "UnhealthyThreshold": 6
        },
        "VPCId": "vpc-***********",
        "BackendServerDescriptions": [
            {
                "InstancePort": 31431,
                "PolicyNames": [
                    "k8s-proxyprotocol-enabled"
                ]
            }
        ],
        "Instances": [
            {
                "InstanceId": "i-085ece5ecf"
            },
            {
                "InstanceId": "i-0b4741cf"
            },
            {
                "InstanceId": "i-03aea99"
            }
        ],
        "DNSName": "***************************",
        "SecurityGroups": [
            "sg-********"
        ],
        "Policies": {
            "LBCookieStickinessPolicies": [],
            "AppCookieStickinessPolicies": [],
            "OtherPolicies": [
                "k8s-proxyprotocol-enabled"
            ]
        },
        "LoadBalancerName": "a1df476de2aa011e9aabe0af927e6700",
        "CreatedTime": "2019-02-07T06:18:01.020Z",
        "AvailabilityZones": [
            "us-east-1a",
            "us-east-1b",
            "us-east-1c"
        ],
        "Scheme": "internet-facing",
        "SourceSecurityGroup": {
            "OwnerAlias": "906391276258",
            "GroupName": "k8s-elb-a1df476de2aa011e9aabe0af927e6700"
        }
    }
]
```

Comment: I tried to add  'k8s-proxyprotocl-enabled' to listener policies out of curiosity using the command 'set-load-balancer-policies-of-listener  --load-balancer-port 4334 --policy-names k8s-proxyprotocol-enabled --region us-east-1 it is throwing this error:        An error occurred (InvalidConfigurationRequest) when calling the SetLoadBalancerPoliciesOfListener operation: k8s-proxyprotocol-enabled cannot be enabled

Answer (score 1):

Yes, setting this annotation is enough to enable Proxy Protocol v1 at Load Balancer level (ELB Classic).

> service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-proxy-protocol: "*"

I`m having ingress-nginx controller exposed via LoadBalancer Service type with aforementioned annotation, and when run it with logging level set to [debug](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/master/docs/troubleshooting.md#debug), I can see that each client request retains real Source IP:

> 172.20.32.78 - [172.20.32.78] - - [08/Feb/2019:18:02:43 +0000] "PROXY TCP4 xxx.xxx.xxx.xx 172.20.xx.xxx 42795 80" 400 157 "-" "-" 0 0.172 []
>
> ---
>
> xxx.xxx.xxx.xx - is my private ip address, not LB one.

The other thing is to enable Proxy Protocol at LB`s backend, so that it can understand forwarded client requests correctly (here are described steps for [NGINX](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/miscellaneous/#source-ip-address)).